# PHP putting path into array

Tags: php

I am trying to populate an array with a path to a file.

```
<?php
session_start(session_id());
$galleryID = $_SESSION['newGalleryId'];
    $path_pages = '../../../../data/gallery/' . $galleryID . '/images/album/';
?>

<?php
class UploadHandler
{
    protected $options;

    function __construct($options=null) {
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
            'upload_dir' => $path_pages,
            'upload_url' => $path_pages,
            'param_name' => 'files'
}
?>
```

I am using the jQuery-file-upload to upload files to a directory. If I hard code the $galleryID in it works fine, but when I try to plug in the $variable it doesn't work. Any ideas why the $galleryID is causing me issues.

Thanks

Comment: `var_dump($galleryID)` and what do you see?  Is it the same value as the hard coded one?

Comment: also, why are you supplying a session id?  try calling `session_start()` without `session_id()`

Comment: `var_dump($path_pages)` and what do you see?

Comment: @Bungdaddy - please post `var_dump($_SESSION['newGalleryId']);`

Comment: I have session id being called as this php is being called in a modal window with an existing session id

Comment: string(42) "../../../../data/gallery/159/images/album/"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
session_start();
$galleryID = $_SESSION['newGalleryId'];
$path_pages = '../../../../data/gallery/' . $galleryID . '/images/album/';
?>
```

Sounds like the $_SESSION is not starting. Adding session_start will instantiate the session and hopefully pull your variable.

**Update**

You should set your options like so:

```
<?php
session_start(session_id());
$galleryID = $_SESSION['newGalleryId'];
    $path_pages = '../../../../data/gallery/' . $galleryID . '/images/album/';

$options = array(
            'upload_dir' => $path_pages,
            'upload_url' => $path_pages,
            'param_name' => 'files');

$upload = new UploadHelper($options);
?>

<?php
class UploadHandler
{
    protected $options;

    function __construct($options=null) {
        $this->options = array(
            'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/'
             );
}
?>
```

Your $path_pages does not have any visibility into the UploadHelper class. Since the class can handle options in the constructor, pass the options when instantiating the class.

Comment: I should have shown that in my example, I do have  session_start(session_id());

Comment: left out the $_SESSION in my example. Edited in example. I have the $galleryID pulling, when I add the $path_pages in the function it's not working. When I hard code in the function, works fine.

Comment: Ok, so you are setting options inside the UploadHelper. Don't. Updating answer.

Comment: I am sure knowing how to implement your code would work great. I couldn't get it to happen. I did however move the $galleryID = $_SESSION['newGalleryId']; into the __construct and it's working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

As it is a pretty incomplete sample, I can only guess:
You may have to reference to `$path_pages` using ether `global $path_pages;` or `$GLOBALS['path_pages']`.